# Why doesnt the text content of the players reset once "reset" button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

```js
    console.log(`on`)

    let p1btn = document.querySelector(`#p1`);     
    let p2btn = document.querySelector(`#p2`);
    let p1Score = document.querySelector(`#p1Score`);
    let p2Score = document.querySelector(`#p2Score`);
    let total = document.querySelector(`span`); 
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`button`);
    let p1Numb = parseInt(p1Score.textContent);
    let p2Numb = parseInt(p2Score.textContent);

    let reset = document.querySelector(`#reset`);

    let winner = document.querySelector(`#hiddenWin`);

    let realwin = document.querySelector(`#winner`);


    reset.addEventListener(`click`,()=>{
    
        p1Score = 0;
        p2Score = 0;
        console.log(total)
        realwin.textContent = ``;
    })

    p1btn.addEventListener(`click`,()=>{
        if(p1Numb<5 &&p2Numb<5){p1Numb ++;
        p1Score.textContent = p1Numb;
    console.log(p1Score.textContent)}
        else{;
            console.log(`p1 wins`);
            realwin.textContent = `p1`}
        })
        
    p2btn.addEventListener(`click`,()=>{
        if(p2Numb<5 &&p1Numb<5){p2Numb ++;
        p2Score.textContent = p2Numb;
        console.log(p2Score)}
        else{realwin.textContent = `p2`}
            })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    </head>
    <body>
       <p>p1 score :  <span id="p1Score">0</span></p>
       <div id="hiddenWin"><h1>winner is:<span id="winner"></span></h1>  </div>
       <p>p2 score : <span id="p2Score">0</span></p>
        <button id="p1">p1</button>
        <button id="p2">p2</button>
        <button id="reset">reset</button>

        <script src="pro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>


</html>
```

Hi, I've been trying to make a score keeper game, but now I've ran into a wall for 50minutes already. I've been trying to reset the numbers of both players once the `reset` button is clicked, but everytime I try to fix it , it just doesnt work the way I want to do, for example it stops updating the numbers of both players, or just doesnt reset at all, so any guidance is really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Typo. You forgot the `textContent`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of simply setting the values to 0. You should use `textContent`:

```
reset.addEventListener('click',() => {
     p1Score.textContent = 0;
     p2Score.textContent = 0;
     console.log(total)
     realwin.textContent = ``;
})
```